# Persisting recursive relationships with Java's Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, reference

I have the following class:

```
public class MyItem {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Set<MyItem> similarItems = new HashSet<MyItem>();

  // constructors
  // getters & setters
}
```

This means that an instance of MyItem contains references to other items of same class.

I have created the following tables with the following columns:

```
[MyItem]:
 id
 name

[MyItemRelations]:
 myItemId  References MyItem
 myItemSimilarId References MyItem
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Is the structure of my tables correct?
2. Have should my .hbm.xml look like? I don't know how to implement this relation.

Comment: The tables look correct. Do you want to do the configuration via xml or would using annotations be ok for you as well? With annotations you might add a `@ManyToMany` to the relation - I guess multiple items could reference the same similar item as well, thus resulting in a n:m relation here.

Comment: I would like to make via .hbm.xml

Comment: This sure looks like the relational model one would use to represent a graph of objects. Relational performance when dealing with graphs is rather poor, especially as the number of nodes and edges grows. You _may_ want to look into using an actual graph database, like Neo4j.

Comment: thanks for neo4j but I stayed at Postgres database and most part of logic is currently implemented according not for neo4j db.. BTW, MyItem entity is only one of few ones which has such structure

Comment: @davs: you do it exactly the same way as if two different entity classes were involved. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-join-m2m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<set name="similarItems" table="MyItemRelations">
    <key column="myItemId"/>
    <many-to-many column="myItemSimilarId" class="MyItem"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Do I need to declare any hibernate config for table 'MyItemRelation' except this set for MyItem table ???